# How do I get post page 11? ASP.net and stateview page (python)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, python-3.x, python-requests, reverse-engineering

Web site in question is [this one](http://www.aam-us.org/about-museums/find-a-museum). I have managed to replicate post request to get results. The problem is that page index changes from 00 to 11 only. When there are some 500 pages. So it appears that page state is stored somewhere and this index relies on the state solely to paginate further. Need some hint on where to go from here.

How do I get post page 11?
Thanks for any thought.
The code is too long to include it here( due to payload lenth). But i can send it on request.

here is the pagination function

```
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
```

And pagination links.
[image]

Another pagination links for next 10 pages. To show they look absolutely the same.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a greate step by step tutorial on this topic [here](http://toddhayton.com/2015/05/04/scraping-aspnet-pages-with-ajax-pagination/)

It appears that i have to extract and update the state and validate values for each set of 10 pages , then scrape results in a loop using pagination and do so in a loop.